# Moo, lazy attributes, and default/coerce invocation

Tags: perl, moo

My Moo based class has both lazy & non-lazy attributes which have both `default` and `coerce` subs.  If I don't initialize the attributes I'm finding that both `default` and `coerce` subs are called for the normal attribute, but only `default` is called for the lazy attribute. That seems inconsistent.  Here's sample code:

```
package Foo;
use Moo;

has nrml => ( is => 'ro',
              default => sub { print "nrml default\n" },
              coerce  => sub { print "nrml coerce\n" } 
            );

has lazy => ( is => 'ro',
              lazy => 1,
              default => sub { print "lazy default\n" },
              coerce  => sub { print "lazy coerce\n" }
            );



my $q = Foo->new( );

$q->lazy;
```

The output is:

```
nrml default
nrml coerce
lazy default
```

I only expect `coerce` to run if I provide a value in the constructor.  More importantly I expect the same sequence of execution  (either `default` or `default` and `coerce`) from both lazy and normal attributes.

So, are my expectations off, is this a bug, or what? Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you use a 'builder' rather than default for anything more trivial from a simple scalar for your default values. this is not an answer to your question but some suggestion.

Comment: Isn't `builder` designed for situations where child classes need access to the parent's attribute creation method so that they can modify it?  For classes which will not be subclassed `default` seems more to the point.

Comment: For completeness I replaced default with a builder; same results as before.

Comment: With Moo 0.9.7 i got in output only default lines: `nrml default
lazy default
`

Comment: I should have mentioned the version I'm using: 0.9.13.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Current status: fix shipped in 009014

One of those two is a bug.

In fact, thinking about it, one could argue either way about whether coercions -should- be fired on defaults but since Moose does do so, and since coercions are structural (unlike type checks, which are often used for assertion-like things and should always pass except in the presence of a bug), I think it falls that way.

... in fact, the problem is that Method::Generate::Accessor when it fires _use_default always wraps it in _generate_simple_set, when it's _generate_set that provides the isa+coerce+trigger wrapping - and I'm fairly sure that Moose fires all three when it's applying a default, so we need to too.

It's not an entirely trivial fix to make though, because I didn't parameterise _generate_set to take a value indicating how to generate the value to set. I'll try and sort it out tomorrow since I'm planning to cut a release then.

If you want support for Moo from the developers, please contact bugs-Moo@rt.cpan.org or join #web-simple on irc.perl.org - it's sheer luck that somebody on the IRC channel saw this question and asked about it :)

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I wanted to make sure I wasn't doing something stupid before filing a bug report.  Happens sometimes.

Comment: Totally, and I appreciate trying to keep the bug queue clean! But equally I'm quite happy with you asking on IRC if you're doing something stupid, or even coming onto IRC and waving a stack overflow link at us :)

Answer (score 3):

That would qualify as a bug to me. Either the value from `default` is expected to be of the right type, or it's not. Having and enforcing the expectation only half of the time makes no sense.